# How to count the number of times two values occurred inside a group by object in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (Users and session). The users table has the combination of users (user1 and user2 along with their ids). From the session table, I want to group by sessionID and count the number of times the pairs in users table occur in the grouped by objects from session table.

For eg, let's take the first pair in users table (xxx, yyy). Now, this pair exists in sessionID 1000 as well as in 2000. So, I want #sessions in users table for that pair to have 2 as the value. Similarly, for all the pairs.

A rough idea I have is to groupby sessionID and see if the pair from users table exists in that grouped by object, if yes, count that group as 1 and sum over all the groups that contain this pair. And of the 2 times that the pair occurred, how many times did user1 click (user1clicks) and how many times did user2 click (user2clicks).

I am not able to translate this into a query. Really struggling to solve this... Any help is much appreciated!

Users table:

```
| user1 | id1 | user2 | id2 | 
-----------------------------
| xxx   | 1   | yyy   | 2   |
| xxx   | 1   | zzz   | 3   |
| yyy   | 2   | zzz   | 3   |
```

Session table:

```
| user |  id   | sessionID | clicked |
--------------------------------------
| xxx  |  1    |  1000     |  yes    |
| yyy  |  2    |  1000     |   no    |
| xxx  |  1    |  2000     |   no    |
| yyy  |  2    |  2000     |   no    |
| xxx  |  1    |  3000     |   no    |
| zzz  |  1    |  3000     |  yes    |
```

Output:

```
| user1 | id1 | user2 | id2 | #sessions | user1clicks | user2clicks|
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| xxx   | 1   | yyy   | 2   |     2     |  1          |   0        |
| xxx   | 1   | zzz   | 3   |     1     |  1          |   0        |
| yyy   | 2   | zzz   | 3   |     0     |  0          |   0        |
```

Comment: The users table has got twice as many columns as it ought to

Comment: @Strawberry: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Not (yet) an answer; too long for a comment:

You need 3 tables;

```
users
user_id | user
-----------------------------
       1 | xxx  
       2 | yyy   
       3 | zzz   

combinations 
user_id1 | user_id2 
-----------------------------
       1   | 2   
       1   | 3   
       2   | 3   

sessions 
session_id    | user_id   | sessionID | clicked |
--------------------------------------
101    |  1    |  1000     |  yes    |
102    |  2    |  1000     |   no    |
103    |  1    |  2000     |   no    |
104    |  2    |  2000     |   no    |
105    |  1    |  3000     |   no    |
105    |  1    |  3000     |  yes    |
```